# Shopify Drop down Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I'm building a web store on shopify. I want to add a validation to dropdown that if no size/value is selected from drop down, it automatically select 1st size/value. when we click on add to cart button.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this HTML:

```
<select id="drop">
    <option value="0">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<button id="add">Add to cart</button>
```

Use this javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $drop = $("#drop");
    $("#add").on("click", function() {
        if($drop.val() == 0) {
            $drop.val(1);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/82vrccem/1/

Answer (score 0):

**Here I have mention a drop-down list and after that the JavaScript validation also given.**

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Option One</option>
    <option value="2">Option Two</option>
    <option value="3">Option Three</option>
</select>
```

**Use the flowing JavaScript validation for upper drop-down list.**

```
function Validate()
    {
        var e = document.getElementById("dropdown");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        //if you need text to be compared then use
        var strUser1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        if(strUser==0) //for text use if(strUser1=="Select")
            {
                alert("Please select a user");
            }
    }
```